# Add value from Array to other array

Tags: arrays, angular

**Component**

```
export class AllUserComponent implements OnInit {
  //Here is saving all users from database
  allUsers: Array<Object>;
  roleName: any[] = []; //here I want roles property from each object from allUsers

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    //Take from UserService getAll method and subscribe to add all users from database
    this.userService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
      this.allUsers = data.allUsers;
      console.log(this.allUsers)
    });

  }
```

**Service**

```
  getAll(): Observable<AllUsers> {
    return this.http.get<AllUsers>(this.url);
  }
```

**Model**

```
export interface AllUsers{
    allUsers: string[];
}
```

[image: allUsers array]

I want to get roles which are nested values in each object of `allUser` array and add it to `roleName` array and display in `Roles` column in `table` in HTML view.

Comment: this question actually has nothing to do with angular, it is just JavaScript.

Comment: Please show us what you tried as the mentioned example is all about fetching data.

Comment: could you show sample data of `this.allUsers`?

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
this.allUsers.forEch(user => {
  user.roleNames.push(user.roles);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets's change that string array first

```
export interface AllUsers{
    allUsers: User[]; // shouldn't be a string array?!
}
```

Add the user

```
export interface User {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string; 
  email: string;
  password: string;
  roles: Role[];
}
```

And Role

```
export interface Role {
  id: number;
  name: string
}
```

Try to avoid using subscribe, use async pipe instead. You could use lodash to handle your arrays.

```
export class AllUserComponent implements OnInit {
  allUsers$: Observable<User[]>;
  distinctRoles$: Observable<Role[]>;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Take from UserService getAll method
    this.allUsers$ = this.userService.getAll().pipe(
      map((all: AllUsers) => all.allUsers),
    );

    // map the roles
    this.distinctRoles$ = this.allUsers$.pipe(
      map((allUsers: User[]) => _.flatMap(allUsers, 'roles')), // import * as _ from 'lodash'
      map((allRoles: Role[][]) => _.flatten(allRoles)),
      map((allRoles: Role[]) => _.uniq(allRoles)), // remove the line if you don't want disctinct
    );
  }
```

And "subscribe" to your Observables in your template with async pipe

```
<div *ngFor="let role of disctictRoles$ | async">
```

Comment: In this solution allUsers show users from database, but the problem is in display roles to appropriate user, because all roles in disctictRoles display in each row :/ https://ibb.co/wYCwGVK here is photo how it display

Answer (score -1):

As i understood; you need to show user roles besides its details, is that true?

I think you are using `matTable` or at least `*ngFor`; so you need to add a function to get appropriate roles; like:

```
getRoles(user: Object) {
    return user.roles.reduce((str, role) => {
        // add role name if this is the first role; else add role to string then return it    
        return str? str += ', ' + role.name: role.name;
    }, '');
}
```

It's not necessary to use reduce function; you can use temporary variable with an ordinary loop; but this is cleaner way.

Then from HTML you can call it in roles `td`; like:

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of allUsers">
    <!-- previous details-->
    <td> {{getRoles(user)}} </td>
</tr>
```

Read more about [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function.

Comment: Thank you; he can move that function to a pipe.