# Angular: selected directive on input not working

Tags: html, angular

I have the following select in my template:

```
   <select class="form-control" formControlName="tipo" name="tipo">
       <option value="" selected disabled>(Select an option)</option> 
        <option value="FACT">Factura</option>
        <option value="NOCRE">Nota Crédito</option>
   </select>
```

however, despite I have put the `selected` directive to the first one, it does not show if the user does not click the `select`. It behaves like another `option` tag.

How can I make this `option` visible when the component loads without user interaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since value is `""` for 'Select..' option, set value `""` in it's formcontrol

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-vbhfx9?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)**

Try like this:

```
this.yourForm= new FormGroup({
    'tipo':new FormControl(''),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why not Adding a model :

in your class :

```
tipo: string = "";
```

in HTML :

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="tipo" class="form-control">
       <option value="" selected disabled>(Select an option)</option> 
        <option value="FACT">Factura</option>
        <option value="NOCRE">Nota Crédito</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: Reactive form and Template driven form shouldn't be mixed

Comment: Some else hate me Hahaha

Comment: Haha.. Check my answer in this: (Downvote for no reason) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58009811/add-value-from-array-to-other-array/58009880#58009880